# How Do I combine two table objects without using Join in Entity Framework MVC?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework - Code first approach. I want to Join two tables to get the data. I found the query in SQL. But Am struggling in Entity Framework to frame that query.

Here is the Sql query:

Groups Table:
GroupID Name ParentID
1       xxx   5
2       yyy   5
3       zzz   10

Global Table:

RegionID Name ParentID
1        India    5
2        Ireland  10
3        Austria  10

From the application i can pass only RegionID which is Global Table. For that region i have to take the Groups Name. But Groups table has ParentID only.

select p.Name from Global g , Groups p where p.RegionID=g.ParentID and g.RegionID=2

Here is the Entity Framework code:

model.Groups = new SelectList(_unitOfWork.GroupRepository.GetWithNoTracking(), "GroupId", "Name", model.GroupID);

The above EF using one repository that is Groups table. Now I want to combine with Global Repository as well.

If I use Join in sql query, am not getting correct data. Getting more records. So, Please help me to find out the EF query without using JOIN Clause.

Regards,
Vanmathi

Comment: can you please give more details... the sql query that you want to implement in EF will help to understand your problem

Comment: I have edited my question. pls check

Comment: I can assume you have a Foreign Key relationship between these two tables...? right?

Comment: You're looking for *navigation properties*. Please use proper [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) when asking a question.

Comment: yes , there is foreign key relationship between those tables. I would know the syntax of that lammada expression query in EF

Answer (score 0):

Try this lambda expression

`var RegionNames = _unitOfWork.GlobalRepository
                    .Where(g=>g.RegionId==2)
                    .SelectMany(g=>g.Groups.Select(r=>r.Name))`

Here it will select all the Group.Name records whose corresponding Global.RegionID=2

Let me know if its what you need or anything else...
This is a representation of the SQL query that you have provided...
Happy to help.

Comment: here, you are using only GroupRespository. But I have to GlobalRespository as well.